# How to add property to array of objects if not found in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object

I would like to know if  property not found just add to array of object in javascript

In arrobj, one specific object has no value property, so need to add using javascript

```
var arrobj=[
  {id:1, name: "ram", value: 100},
  {id:2, name: "ben", value: 100},
  {id:3, name: "laks"}
]

Expected Output
[
  {id:1, name: "ram", value: 100},
  {id:2, name: "ben", value: 100},
  {id:3, name: "laks", value: null}
]
```

I tried

```
const result = arrobj.forEach(e=>{
  if(!e.hasOwnProperty("value"){
   e.value=null
  }

});
```

Comment: How exactly did your attempt not work?

Comment: Also note that `.forEach()` won't return anything, so there's no point saving into `result`.

Comment: @Pointy thanks for reply, any other ways to do,

Comment: You have not explained what's wrong with your current code.

Answer (score 0):

There is only a single typo in the approach you used. You missed to close a `)` in the if statement. The following works:

```js
var arrobj=[
  {id:1, name: "ram", value: 100},
  {id:2, name: "ben", value: 100},
  {id:3, name: "laks"}
]
const result = arrobj.forEach(e=>{
  if(!e.hasOwnProperty("value")){
   e.value=null
  }

});
console.log(arrobj)
```

Here's an Approach using a for loop.

```js
var arrobj=[
  {id:1, name: "ram", value: 100},
  {id:2, name: "ben", value: 100},
  {id:3, name: "laks"}
]
for (var i = 0; i<arrobj.length;i++){
   if (arrobj[i].id == undefined){arrobj[i].id = null}
   if (arrobj[i].name == undefined){arrobj[i].name = null}
   if (arrobj[i].value == undefined){arrobj[i].value = null}
}
console.log(arrobj)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the map

```
  const result = arrobj.map((e) => {
  if (!e.hasOwnProperty('value')) {
    e.value = null;
  }
   return e;
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `Array#forEach` use `Array#map` **AND** return `e` as in @Hakime Sheikhalishahi's answer.
**Please note:** Other than a missing `)` in the if statement your code works only that it changes the original array. From the variables you've used it appears that your intention is to create a new array. `Array#map` always creates a new array and leaves the original one intact.

```js
const 
arrobj=[ {id:1, name: "ram", value: 100}, {id:2, name: "ben", value: 100}, {id:3, name: "laks"} ],

result = arrobj.map(e=> {
    if(!e.hasOwnProperty("value")) {
        e.value = null
    }
    return e;
});

console.log( result );
```

**Destructuring**

You can also use destructuring as follows:

```js
const 
arrobj=[ {id:1, name: "ram", value: 100}, {id:2, name: "ben", value: 100}, {id:3, name: "laks"} ],

result = arrobj.map(({value,...rest}) => ({...rest,value: value || null}));

console.log( result );
```